# How to properly use unit-testing's assertRaises() with NoneType objects

Tags: python, unit-testing

I did a simple test case:

```
def setUp(self):

  self.testListNone = None

def testListSlicing(self):

  self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.testListNone[:1])
```

And I am expecting the test to pass, but I am getting an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.testListNone[:1])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

I thought that assertRaises will pass since TypeError exception will be raised. What is the explanation?

Comment: https://ongspxm.github.io/blog/2016/11/assertraises-testing-for-errors-in-unittest/

You can refer to this document as he/she has explained why use a lambda/context manager to wrap the code

Answer (score 300, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7 or above, you can use the ability of [assertRaises](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to be used as a context manager and do:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    self.testListNone[:1]
```

If you are using Python 2.6, another way beside the one given until now is to use [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/0.5.1) which is a back port of [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html)'s new features to Python 2.6, and you can make it work using the code above.

N.B: I'm a big fan of the new feature (SkipTest, test discovery, etc.) of unittest, so I intend to use unittest2 as much as I can. I advise to do the same, because there is a lot more than what unittest come with in Python 2.6 or lower.

Comment: 2.7 _or above_ .. are you hiding Python 2.8 from us?

Comment: The code you mention does not seem to help with the problem of ending the script before it comes to the assert-comparison. Still fails the test (using python 3.10)

Answer (score 181):

The problem is the `TypeError` gets raised 'before' `assertRaises` gets called since the arguments to `assertRaises` need to be evaluated before the method can be called. You need to pass a `lambda` expression like:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda: self.testListNone[:1])
```

Comment: Probably best answer

Comment: The answer from @unutbu shows how to call `assertRaises` (no lambda necessary)

Answer (score 109):

The usual way to use `assertRaises` is to call a function:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, test_function, args)
```

to test that the function call test_function(args) raises a TypeError.

The problem with `self.testListNone[:1]` is that Python evaluates the expression immediately, before the `assertRaises` method is called. The whole reason why `test_function` and `args` is passed as separate arguments to `self.assertRaises` is to allow `assertRaises` to call `test_function(args)` from within a `try...except` block, allowing `assertRaises` to catch the exception.

Since you've defined `self.testListNone = None`, and you need a function to call, you might use [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) like this:

```
import operator
self.assertRaises(TypeError, operator.itemgetter, (self.testListNone,slice(None,1)))
```

since

```
operator.itemgetter(self.testListNone,slice(None,1))
```

is a long-winded way of saying `self.testListNone[:1]`, but which separates the function (`operator.itemgetter`) from the arguments.

Comment: For a single assertRaises, this looks like the best answer. For a large bank of exception based tests (assuming they all have the same exception type) the with self.assertRaises(...) would be a good choice.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the correct answer since it actually explains the problem.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, which explains the problem.

Comment: Can you please help me in a related question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909935/how-do-you-show-an-error-message-when-a-test-does-not-throw-an-expected-exceptio

Comment: +1 It can be simplified to `self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.testListNone.__getitem__, slice(None,1))`, because the operator.itemgetter adds some small useless complexity.

Answer (score 38):

A complete snippet would look like the following. It expands [mouad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103825/how-to-properly-use-unit-testings-assertraises-with-nonetype-objects/6103983#6103983) to asserting on the error's message (or generally the string representation of its arguments), which may be useful.

```
from unittest import TestCase


class TestNoneTypeError(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.testListNone = None

  def testListSlicing(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as ctx:
        self.testListNone[:1]
    self.assertEqual("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", str(ctx.exception))
```