# Python self.assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, assertraises

I have a small code as below, please help me how to write this in a correct way. I want to check if ID is present in the `value` and if not then it raises an exception.

```
value = ({'av' : '123', 'user' : 'abc', 'version' : 'xyz'})

with self.assertRaises(IndexError, value[0]["ID"]):
    print "not an error"
```

Comment: fwiw, your code raises for the wrong reason, `({...})` is not a 1-tuple of dict, it's just a dict (with some extra parentheses), you'd need `({...},)`

Answer (score 5):

Problem with your code is that `value[0]["ID"]` is just an arbitrary argument, and in Python arguments are evaluated before performing function call. So in your case `assertRaises` has no chance to intercept error, as it's not being called.

I guess you're looking for this snippet, if you wish to stick with context manager based approach, which is useful in case you need to evaluate statements or multiple expressions at once:

```
with self.assertRaises(IndexError):
    value[0]["ID"]
```

Or you can work this way, if you need to resolve single expression (statements won't work in lambdas):

```
self.assertRaises(IndexError, lambda: value[0]["ID"])
```

For additional information on this, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103825/how-to-properly-use-unit-testings-assertraises-with-nonetype-objects), as it seemingly addresses your issue regarding how to properly use `assertRaises`.

Also please note in your case `value` is just dict, not tuple, despite parentheses — in order to make `value` single-element tuple, use `foo = (bar, )` syntax — trailing coma is needed to distinguish from precedence override parentheses, like in `(2 + 2) * 3`.

Also in unit-testing you don't generally need to output anything related to status of your assertions — in case it passes or fails it's job of unit-testing framework to form appropriate report. But if you are willing to print it anyway, just include `print()` after your assertion — because if assertion fails, test stops running, and control won't reach your `print()`.

Comment: alright thanks for your response. I will try it and respond you.

Comment: I tried using this: and its still not working, its throwing an error.
self.assertRaises(IndexError, lambda: value[0]["ID"])

Comment: "value" contains an array and I am not worried about the print at the end. I just want to use self.assertRaises function to evaluate if the array contains ID.

Comment: Well, that's because accessing missing key on dicts raises `KeyError`, not `IndexError`, which is raised on missing indices. So you're basically asserting for wrong exception — try `assertRaises(KeyError, lambda: value[0]["ID"])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case you did not insist on the `assertRaises` method, I would rather choose `assertIn`:

```
value = ({'av' : '123', 'user' : 'abc', 'version' : 'xyz'})
self.assertIn('ID', value)
```