# How to assert a raised custom exception in Python with PyUnit?

Tags: python, assert, python-unittest

I want to know how to assert a raised exception in Python? I tried it with assertRaises(ExpectedException) but the test failed and the console output told me that the expected Exception was raised. 
So how could I write this, so that the Exception is captured and asserted right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssertRaises() can test all exception which you raise from the code.

The syntax for using assertRaises is:

```
assertRaises(CustomException, Function that throws the exception, Parameters for function(In case of multiple params, they will be comma separated.))
```

How it works:

When assertRaises is encountered, pyUnit executes the function mentioned inside a Try-Except block with the except block containing the CustomException. If the exception is properly handled, the test passes else it fails.

More on assertRaises can be found at [How to properly use unit-testing's assertRaises() with NoneType objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103825/how-to-properly-use-unit-testings-assertraises-with-nonetype-objects).

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the module throwing the exception and your test code refer to the exception in a different namespace.

So, for example, if you have:

```
# code_to_be_tested.py

from module_with_exception import * # including CustomException

...

raise CustomException()

# test_code.py

import module_with_exception.CustomException as CE

...

with assertRaises(CE) ...
```

This happens because the two files actually end up pointing to different classes/objects.

---

So, two ways around this:

- refer to them in the same way, if at all possible
- if you did something like `from blah import *`, grab the exception from the test module *itself*, as that's the one it's raising (ie, `from code_to_be_tested import CustomException`)